# Reporting Checkboxes Question in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, reporting, looker-studio

I want to create a function name `result` (Google Apps Script) to reporting my checkboxes question but when I run it, Google Sheets says:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined."

I used a step in from a post in the Google Data Studio Forum titled:
[Reporting checkboxes questions on Data Studio](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/41265682)

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, that's the expected behaviour:
[image]

In this case, the function doesn't need to be run; simply save the function (the floppy disk mark) and then create the formula in the required cell.

Adding a [link to the suggestion by Nimantha](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/41265682?msgid=41717401) in the thread (which also includes the steps involved and a GIF of the process from Google Sheets to Google Data Studio). Also, as best practice, adding the contents of the respective post:

Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/4ddc5a3a-84f2-4c0b-af8b-e7a2d6c72212) ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sgJA83OIDVf7R8-azgbcMhEgjFXBQmIngAzarCKVicg/edit?usp=sharing) and Google Forms embedded) to demonstrate, as well as a GIF showing the process below.

### 1) Transform

The Data Need to be transformed from the [Current Wide Table Structure to a Long Data Structure](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6295223). One way this can be achieved in Google Sheets is adapting the idea the by [Shane S_4](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/10143480?hl=en&msgid=21866375). In the App Script below, the third line, targetColumn contains the delimited values, since the initial column is numbered 0 targetColumn = 1  is the 2nd column:

### 1.1) Google App Script

```
function result(range) {
  delimiter = ", "
  targetColumn = 1

  var output2 = [];
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var s = range[i][targetColumn].split(delimiter);
    for(var j=0, jLen=s.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      var output1 = [];
      for(var k=0, kLen=range[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
        if(k == targetColumn) {
          output1.push(s[j]);
        } else {
          output1.push(range[i][k]);
        }
      }
      output2.push(output1);
    }
  }
  return output2;
}
```

### 1.2) Google Sheets Formula

Create a New sheet and add the formula below in cell A1

```
=Result('Form responses 1'!A:B)
```

### 2) Chart (Bar)

- ***Dimension***: What's your favorite food?
- ***Metric***: Record Count
- ***Style (Tab)***: Show Data Labels

### 3) Chart (Alt - Percent)

- ***Dimension***: What's your favorite food?
- ***Metric***: Record Count (Comparison Calculation: Percent of Total)
- ***Style (Tab)***: Show Data Labels